# Iteratively replace values within a group in a conditional cummin manner

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

A subset of an extremely large dataset has two dimensions: One is the group `ORG`, another is distance `dist`, for instance,

1. the row #3 means that there is none (`N=0`) french firm within a 15km radius (to some coordinate).
2. the row #6, there is one (`N=1`) french firm that was established in year 1992 (`FirstEntry=1992`) within a 30km radius (to some coordinate).

I need to efficiently generate a new column `FirstEntry2` as follows:

```
    ORG dist N FirstEntry FirstEntry2
 1: FRA    5 0         NA          NA
 2: FRA   10 0         NA          NA
 3: FRA   15 0         NA          NA
 4: FRA   20 0         NA          NA
 5: FRA   25 0         NA          NA
 6: FRA   30 1       1992        1992 # the first valid firm A w/in 30km radius
 7: FRA   35 2       1994        1992 # firm A must be earliest w/in 35km as well, so replace this with 1992
 8: FRA   40 2       1994        1992 # the same as previous row
 9: FRA   45 2       1994        1992 # the same as previous row
10: FRA   99 2       1994        1992 # the same as previous row
11: JPN    5 0         NA          NA
12: JPN   10 0         NA          NA
13: JPN   15 0         NA          NA
14: JPN   20 0         NA          NA
15: JPN   25 0         NA          NA
16: JPN   30 0         NA          NA
17: JPN   35 1       1995        1995 # w/in 35km, this is earliest, though afar there's a firm est. in 1992
18: JPN   40 2       1992        1992 # so, FirstEntry2 in this row no need to be replaced
19: JPN   45 2       1992        1992 # the same reason, no replace
20: JPN   99 2       1992        1992 # the same reason, no replace
21: DEU    5 0         NA          NA
22: DEU   10 1       1998        1998 # the first valid firm C, w/in 10km radius
23: DEU   15 2       1999        1998 # this firm C must be earliest w/in 15km as well, so replace this with 1998
24: DEU   20 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
25: DEU   25 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
26: DEU   30 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
27: DEU   35 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
28: DEU   40 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
29: DEU   45 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
30: DEU   99 2       1999        1998 # the same as previous row
```

```
# Sorry, there were mistakes when I posted it here at first. (edited)
test <- data.table(ORG = c(rep("FRA", 10), rep("JPN", 10), rep("DEU", 10)),
                   dist = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 99, 
                            5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 99,
                            5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 99), 
                   N = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                         0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                         0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                   FirstEntry = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1992, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1995, 1992, 1992, 1992,
                                  NA, 1998,rep(1999, 8)), 
                   FirstEntry2= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
                                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1995, 1992, 1992, 1992,
                                  NA, rep(1998, 9)))
```

I have tried something like this, but not the desired result

```
test[, FirstEntry2 := shift(FirstEntry), by = .(ORG, cumsum(c(1, +(FirstEntry > shift(FirstEntry) & !is.na(FirstEntry))[-1])))]
```

How can I do it right? Thank you so much!

Comment: Not quite sure about the logic, but could it be a `cummin` problem? `test[!is.na(FirstEntry) , res := cummin(FirstEntry), by = ORG]`

Comment: @Henrik . It's not an intuitive example, and not a problem for `cummin`, instead it was what I needed for `cummin`. The logic behind this is tedious: The original data reports columns about firm_i, observation year, bank branch_j. Since I only need the rows with firm_i - foreign bank branches_j pair, then I calculate the geo distances b/w all these firm-branch pair and split the distance by the interval as the same as `test[[dist]]`. Then I calculate `cumsum()` of #branches & `min(year)` along the dist interval. After this step, `cumsum(N)` is right whereas `min(year)` is not, since .....

Comment: @Henrik,  since .... (1) a firm with further branch may have earlier established branch to provide service for it, like the #row 17 and 18, which is right here. (2) a firm with an earliest branch w/in 30km radius is equivalent to has THIS branch w/in any radius, although there could be a later establish branch w/in any further radius, like #row 6 and 7.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with sufficient complexity. It seems like my code would give the desired result so you need to add the cases where it fails.

Comment: @Henrik what you provided is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a solution,

```
for (col in names(test)) set(test, which(is.na(test[[col]])), col, value = 9999 )

test[, FirstEntry3 := cummin(FirstEntry), 
      by = .(ORG)]

identical(test$FirstEntry2, test$FirstEntry3)
```

No!! My brain was not functional...